# Create Script to clear cell every time sheet is opened

Tags: google-apps-script

I am very new to scrips on google sheets and have been having no success 
I have been trying to create a script that clears the content of 1 cell every time the sheet is opened but have had no luck, i have looked up how to do it but every example i try just errors. I need cell A2 to be clear every time someone new opens the sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vvq7k_sdP2CBLZXzkpfxGvcmoTPdxC0NaH3I7-8wAoo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please share you code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you create the function in the script editor, Goto "Edit->Current Project's Triggers" and click on "add one now". Set the function that you want and under Events, choose "From SpreadSheet". On the next drop down list, choose "On Open"

I have create a function that clear the content of cell "A2" just to show how it works.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var range = sheet.getRange("A2");
  range.clearContent();
}
```

Please Note that after you open the sheet, it will take upto 5 seconds to clear the cell.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i have tied using the same code myself but kept getting errors but this one works.

Comment: If my code works, then please mark my answer as answered :)